# js word counter - when refreshing the page the counter goes back to original count

Tags: javascript, forms, refresh, cpu-word

Whenever someone refreshes my page or submits the form on the page (and there is an error), the word counter goes back to the original amount of characters. I have a word counter in my form for a particular field.

As such, whenever someone tries to fill out our form, our validation tells them that they have to fill out the specific question and does not allow them to submit the form. I realize I could quick-fix the validation by taking out where it says that the textarea cannot be left empty. But that is not a solution I can envisage.

Here is the code I have:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function textCounter(field,cntfld,maxlimit) {
    var cntfield = document.getElementById(cntfld);
if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
else
cntfield.innerHTML = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}

</script>
```

Followed by my html

```
  <div>
    <textarea class="cf_inputbox required" rows="7" id="text_id"  title="title_test"  cols="50" name="text_id" onKeyDown="textCounter(this,'counter_length',200)"
onKeyUp="textCounter(this,'counter_length',200)"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <span id="counter_length">200</span> Left
  </div>
```

How could I modify my code so that if the page is refreshed OR if the form is submitted (with errors - and thus the validation kicks in), that the word counter would stay at the CURRENT number and not go back to 200?

Comment: Execute the function on pageload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the function, that will be executed when the page loads. Something like this:

```
<script>
     function onPageLoad() {
          var field = document.getElementById("text_id");
           textCounter(field,'counter_length',200)
       }
</script>
<body onload="onPageLoad()">
   <!-- your markup-->
</body>
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vUkk6/2/)